# Typical way to clean up background work in a user-facing component

Tags: go, concurrency, background-process

Assuming I want to return an instance of a "stateful" component to a user, what is the typical way I can cleanup/join background work within that instance? And are there any patterns to avoid viral propagation of explicit cleanup functions all the way to the root code?

For example, let's assume I am returning a client to a database to the user. In this client, I have a loop that periodically polls the server for updates. Now any time this exists within an ownership DAG (like as a member variable in another struct, or as a list in another struct). Requiring an explicit Close() will bubble up virally throughout the call stack. As each upwards link in the DAG will require a Close() as well. All the way to the function that owns the root instance (eg. main() will be required to call Close() on the root server instance, which will require an implementation of Close() so it cleans up background behind itself, etc). Something like the below

```
type DbClient struct { ... }
func Cleanup(client DbClient) { ... }

type Component struct { 
  client DbClient 
  ... 
}
func Cleanup(component Component) { ... }

type Server struct { 
  component Component
  ... 
}
func Cleanup(server Server) { ... }
```

Is there any other way to handle these cases? Or is an explicit Close() function the recommendation for such stateful components?

Comment: If a resource needs to be closed, then it should have a `Close` method, which should be called when the resource no longer needed. "Viral propagation" does not seem to be a relevant concern; it's unclear what the actual problem presented here is.

Comment: If it is appropriate to do so, you could potentially skip some hops in the call chain using context cancellation, would that help? You'd still have to propagate the context, but it would be at creation time rather than at close time. I'm not sure if that's an improvement in your use case.

Comment: @Adrian Hmm I'm not too familiar with what cancellation means in this context :/ I've updated the question to clarify the "viral propagation" bit!

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/context/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem you mentiond: "upwards link in the DAG will require a Close()" & "all the way to the func that owns root instance.

Go has [struct embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) feature. Go favors composition over inheritance.

*There's an important way in which embedding differs from subclassing. When we embed a type, the methods of that type become methods of the outer type, but when they are invoked the receiver of the method is the inner type, not the outer one.*

```
package main

import "fmt"

type DbClient struct{}

func (client *DbClient) Cleanup() {
    fmt.Println("Closed called on client")
}

type Component struct {
    *DbClient
}

type Server struct {
    *Component
}

func main() {

    client := DbClient{}

    component := Component{&client}

    server := Server{&component}

    server.Cleanup()
}
```